# Differenciate first run from others in a standalone function?

Tags: javascript, architecture, closures

I have a project where each function is fully independent, like a module.

It means I can copy this function into another project and all is working fine.

However, I have a case where one of these functions acts differently if it is running for the first time or if it has already been running previously.

For now, the only way I have found to achieve this is to use an extrernal boolean, what I would like to avoid, like this :

```
var init = true;
function someFunc() {
    if (init) {
        init = false;
        // First run code
    }
    else {
        // Not first run code
    }
}
```

Is there some way in javascript to achieve the same in a **"standalone"** function, I mean, without external boolean ?

Comment: When you say "copy" you mean physically copy paste the code, or pass by reference to some other code? If it is the case of former, wrap the function in a closure function with a variable indicating weather or not the function already ran, then return the inner function.

Comment: I mean physically copy past the code in another project file.

Comment: You could use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE): wrap your function inside: `(function() { ... })()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what i described above in the comment. Do note that there probably are more efficient ways to do this in less lines of code, however for the purpose of learning I think this is the best way to write it.

```js
var myFunction = (function(){
  let firstTime = true;
  return function trueFunction(){
    if (firstTime){
      console.log('first!');
      firstTime = false;
    } else {
      console.log("first, oh goddamnit!");
    }
  }
})()

myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

> Generators are functions which can be exited and later re-entered.
>   Their context (variable bindings) will be **saved** across re-entrances.

So you could not only differentiate first run, you could also differentiate each specific run. like this:

```js
function* foo() {
  yield 'first'; //first time
  yield 'second'; //second time
  yield 'third'; //third time
}

var str = "";
for (let val of foo()) {
  str = str +" "+val;
}

console.log(str);//first second third
```